# How to run selenium test from HTMl file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have 500 - 1000 test cases in selenium webdriver and I am using testNG and I want to run different test cases everytime.....I want to design html page and add classes name and checkbox and want to run test from there.... is it possible and is there any other way to achieve this. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "run selenium test from HTMl file"? It's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

On basis of the selection of test classes or even test methods, you can run the testNg tests manually from your code or even create a synthetic testng.xml and run that.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to design UI properly and use python script and if-else conditional statements to find out which class is checked or mark true to run automation tests.

You need to use html file with class names listed, javascript to fetch which classes are selected and send that array to server side.

Server side read that array and add those functions to the script to run.

It is little bit complicated task but good to write this script.